# Is the private key inside a cert encrytped?

Tags: security, certificate, private-key

I'm wondering if the private key inside a cert encrypted so that even someone somehow exported my private key, it still cannot be used without decryption?

Comment: I cannot help you on how, but wikipedia say "However, for additional security the private key itself can be locked with a passphrase."

Comment: What do you mean by _"private key inside a cert"_?

Comment: Do you have to enter a passphrase to use your certificate? If so, yes. If not, most likely no.